# php :Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp

I Have a big problem And I Wish get Solved for this problem  here 
I Try to Connect to Sql Server 2008 R2 using:

1. php 5.6.11
2. Xampp 5.6.3
3. Sql Server 2008 r2
4. Using sql server drivers for PHP  (php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dl &
   php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll)

and my code to try connection is :

```
 $serverName = "Mahmoud-HP\SQL2008R2"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"HR16", "UID"=>"Mahmoud", "PWD"=>"123" , "MultipleActiveResultSets" => false);
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
```

but when run the page this message come to me

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\testsqlserver\index.php on

What is solution for this problem

Comment: Create a php page with `phpinfo()`. That should show you if your SQL server drivers are correctly being loaded.

Comment: jszobody 
how i Show it in this page ?? what is flag ??!!
can you give me more explain

Comment: *undefined function* clearly means the extension is not installed and your description of how you installed is basically "Using". In any case, I suggest you run PHP from the command line so you have a chance to see initialisation errors. Just `php -v` should trigger them.

Comment: @PERSON Fire a plain text editor (not a word processor), type `<?php phpinfo();` in it, save it as `C:\xampp\htdocs\testsqlserver\phpinfo.php` and then load it in your browser (it should be the same URL you are already using, except that ending with `phpinfo.php`).

Comment: Did you restart your apache after editing the php.ini?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the SQL Server native driver for php.

Download from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098

Example Code:

```
$serverName = "tcp:ServerID.database.windows.net, 1433";

$connectionOptions = array("Database" => "DatabaseName", 

                           "UID" => "Username@ServerID",

                           "PWD" => "password");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);



if($conn === false)

{

    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));

}
```

EDIT

Make sure you load BOTH dll's listed:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

and

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

Comment: Native Driver is necessary for the extension to actually work, but you need to install the extension first and the OP hasn't (thus the *undefined function* error message).

Comment: @Álvaro González you're in right. I have edited my answer

Comment: this works well on local (osx) but won't on windows server 2012, I don't know why yet