# I need to connect SQL SERVER to my codeigniter project

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

No it's not a Duplicate. In that also they said to include dll files. I did it but still I got same error

I need to connect sql server to codeigniter project. And I added

extension = php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll in php.ini

But still I got fatal Error.

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'ADMIN-PC\SQLEXPRESS',
    'username' => 'name',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'dbname',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

This is what I got while run this on localhost (Appache Server)

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\system\database\drivers\sqlsrv\sqlsrv_driver.php on line 144

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Error

Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Filename: sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php

Line Number: 144

Backtrace:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php :Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv\_connect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36035791/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-sqlsrv-connect)

Comment: No I tried that too but I am facing same error

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate I tried many answers but I still can't connect

Comment: you need to understand that you have to download the compiled dlls and copy them to the php ext dir and include them as extension in your php.ini dir otherwise this won't work - if you need to know which sqlsrv version you should install take a look @https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017, you can also use the pdo drivers - its up to you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts I finally find solution.

All you need to follow below steps.

Step 1: Find version of your php by using php_info().

Step 2 : You have to find exact sqlsrv compiler (which means the .dll file) for your php version.

Eg : if you are using php 7.1 then the exact compiler is php_sqlsrv_71_ts.dll
     like if you using php 5.6 then it should be php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

Step 3 : Add this in your xampp/php/ext folder

Step 4 : Then add this line in your php.ini file
         extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_.dll

Step 5 : Now stop and start Apache server.

Now You can find sqlsrv in php_info().

if you didn't find then you should check error log.

That's all Thank you folks :)